# jQuery $.get() issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new with jQuery and JavaScript. I'm trying to make a HTTP GET request with the `get()` function. Below I've reported a part of my code. I don't understand why the http request doesn't work. Thanks for any advice!

```
    var jqxhr = $.get("http://lyricwiki.org/api.php?func=getSong&artist=Tool&song=Schism&fmt=xml", 
    function() {
         alert("success");
     })
    .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
    .error(function() { alert("error"); })
    .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Have you looked in the error console or debugger console to see if there are any javascript errors reported?  Are you calling this from a webpage on the lyricwiki.org domain?

Comment: I am guessing this cross-domain security. What domain is your website on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you're serving this on a different domain than lyricwiki.org, in which case you're violating the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

---

Edit: the good news is that they seem to have a funky alternative to JSONP that will let you request it cross-domain as a raw JavaScript file: http://lyrics.wikia.com/LyricWiki:REST#Response_Formats.  Here's an example: http://lyrics.wikia.com/api.php?artist=Slipknot&song=Before_I_Forget&fmt=js

Comment: Ok thanks everybody for the very quickie and accurate answers! Tomorrow I'll try and I'll let you know! Thanks again!

Comment: You're right man, the problem is the same origin policy. I share this link [link] (http://techblog.molindo.at/2008/07/access-to-lyricwikiorgs-rest-api-with-pure-javascript.html) so if anyone is interested about it, can see how I solved. Thanks everybody again! (and sorry for my bad english!)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is perfectly good, what i assume that your domains are different.

Domain where you execute code needs to be same as lyricwiki.org

That is cross domain policy and its not possible to get any data using AJAX from another domain.

IF this is the case try using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

I hope this helps.